# Please analyze a regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

I have read some documents about regular expressions but I can not analyze this regex.
I have just understand `^.+` is create some any characters and then `\\@` is a `@` character. The rest of the chain I can't explain clearly.

```
^.+\\@(\\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\\]?)$
```

Comment: FYI, [python regular expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/zX7cX1). This website would show explanations of each element in the regex. You'll need to replace `\\` with `\` first i.e. use:

```
^.+\@(\[?)[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+\.([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$
```

The explaination is:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
.+ matches any character (except newline)
    Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
\@ matches the character @ literally
1st Capturing group (\[?)
    \[? matches the character [ literally
        Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]+ match a single character present in the list below
    Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
    A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
    0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
    \\-\\ a single character in the range between the following two characters
        \\ the literal character \
        \\ the literal character \
    . the literal character .
\. matches the character . literally
2nd Capturing group ([a-zA-Z]{2,3}|[0-9]{1,3})
    1st Alternative: [a-zA-Z]{2,3}
        [a-zA-Z]{2,3} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Between 2 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            a-z a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)
            A-Z a single character in the range between A and Z (case sensitive)
    2nd Alternative: [0-9]{1,3}
        [0-9]{1,3} match a single character present in the list below
            Quantifier: Between 1 and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
            0-9 a single character in the range between 0 and 9
3rd Capturing group (\]?)
    \]? matches the character ] literally
        Quantifier: Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Comment: Would be better as a comment, but its a fair answer since the question is asking something that a tool will do on its own.

Comment: Also, there are a couple of unnecessary escapes to begin with (`@` doesn't need to be escaped at all, neither does `]` or `.` within a character class).